# Testing scroll position React custom hook

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-hooks

Using React I've extracted some logic from a component into a custom hook to manage the state of an element whether or not it is sticky. This is dependant on the top scroll position of the containing drawer component.

How can I test the returned state from this hook? It's dependant on the scroll position of elements so I presume it'll involve some kind of mocking? I'm using React testing library and Jest.

```
export const useDrawerStickyNav = (
  drawerNavigationRef: React.RefObject<HTMLElement>,
  drawerIsOpen: boolean,
) => {
  const [isNavSticky, setIsNavSticky] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const drawerHeaderHeight = 60;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (drawerIsOpen) {
      const cachedRef = drawerNavigationRef.current as HTMLElement;
      const cachedRefTopPosition = cachedRef.offsetTop - drawerHeaderHeight;
      const drawerContent = document.querySelector('.drawer__content');

      const handleScroll = () => {
        const drawerScrollPosition = drawerContent?.scrollTop || 0;
        setIsNavSticky(drawerScrollPosition > cachedRefTopPosition);
      };

      drawerContent?.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

      return () => {
        drawerContent?.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
      };
    }
  }, [drawerIsOpen]);

  return { isNavSticky };
};
```

Comment: But why do you use `document.querySelector` after passing a ref? It would be much easier to test when relying on ref only

Comment: The ref is the navigation bar within the drawer component. The `.drawer__content` is the element with the `overflow: scroll` property as the drawer is fixed to the right side of the screen when open.